# Unable to determine most recent event in audit trail using DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm attempting to create a pivot table that shows the historic status of notices as they appeared at the end of a time period. In other words, the count of distinct notice id (NoticeNo) based on its **status** at the end of the visible time period. This **status** can be found by looking at the last row for the time period for a particular notice in the `Audit` table.

I'm using `'calendar'[date]` on rows and `Audit[Status]` on columns

Below is a sample of the `Audit` table.

| NoticeNo | EventDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1423441630 | 7/03/2020 | Active Payment Arrangement |
| 1423441630 | 1/12/2019 | Under Remediation |
| 1423441630 | 2/02/2018 | Under Remediation |
| 1805345209 | 24/09/2020 | Work Ongoing |
| 1805345209 | 8/03/2020 | Under Remediation |
| 1805345209 | 7/03/2020 | Under Remediation |
| 1805345209 | 7/03/2020 | Under Remediation |

I have attempted to filter out any statuses that are not the latest status for each notice in the visible period, but it always takes the latest overall status regardless of the visible period.

This is what I am currently getting:

| Year | Active Payment Arrangement | Under Remediation | Work Ongoing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

This is what I want:

| Year | Active Payment Arrangement | Under Remediation | Work Ongoing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

The DAX below appears to work in DaxStudio, but crashes in PowerPivot. The issue appears to be at the final step when I am attempting to filter the summarized table:

```
=VAR LatestDate =
    MAX ( 'Calendar'[date] )
VAR LatestEvents =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE (
                Audit,
                Audit[NoticeNo],
                Audit[Status],
                "MaxDate", MAX ( Audit[NoticeEventDate] )
            ),
            FILTER ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[date] < LatestDate )
        ),
        ALL ( Audit[Status] ),
        ALL ( 'Calendar'[date] )
    )
VAR LatestEventsRanked =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        LatestEvents,
        "DateRank",
            VAR CurrentNotice = [NoticeNo]
            RETURN
                RANKX ( FILTER ( LatestEvents, [NoticeNo] = CurrentNotice ), [MaxDate] )
    )
VAR LatestEventwthContext=
        FILTER (
            LatestEventsRanked,
            [DateRank] = 1 && CONTAINSROW ( VALUES ( Audit[Status] ), [Status] )
        )
RETURN
COUNTROWS(LatestEventwthContext)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any relationships between tables? Do you have a calendar (date dimension) table? A screenshot of your model diagram would be handy.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question as per your suggestions.